# XSLT - How to insert current dateTime in a right way

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am struggling to fix a problem - I tried to insert current date time in XSLT but I got error because of incorrect syntax. My XML file doesn't have date time therefore i need to insert current date time in XSLT file *(date="" with attribute)* - look below:

**XSLT:**

```
<TestList>
  <Header testCode="Test_3334"  testId="" date="">
    <xsl:attribute name="Header/date">
        <xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    <Validation TestName="{Header/Validation/TestName}" TestSurname="{Header/Validation/Surname}" checksum="{Header/Validation/Checksum}" />
  </Header>
  <Tests>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tests/Test"/>
  </Tests>
</TestList>
```

Is there any way to format correct date time in XSLT. Maybe my code is wrong. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What XSLT parser are you using?

Comment: Never tell us "I got an error". Tell us what the error was. Why ask us to solve the problem blindfolded? You might not understand the error message, but we probably will.

Answer (score 5):

The issue may not be with the "current-dateTime()" function, but with the name of the attribute:

```
 <xsl:attribute name="Header/date">
```

You should not specify an xpath expression here, but literally just the name of the attribute, and it will be added to the most recent element you have output

```
 <xsl:attribute name="date">
```

You also don't actually need to have the "date" attribute specified on the **Header** first either (although that won't break anything, as the **xsl:attribute** will overwrite it). This should work:

```
<Header testCode="Test_3334" testId="">
    <xsl:attribute name="date">
        <xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Actually, you can simplify this with Attriute Value Templates. Try this

```
<Header testCode="Test_3334" testId="" date="{current-dateTime()}">
```

Note that you will need to be using an XSLT 2.0 processor for the dateTime function to work.